# Cannot able to play mp3 file in telerik : rad media player

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am not able to play the mp3 file in telerik rad media player.
Here is my try:

```
string filePath =Server.MapPath("~/App_Temp/") + "test.mp3";      
if (testAudios != null)
{
byte[] bytes =Convert.FromBase64String(testAudios.FirstOrDefault().reAudio);
using (var audioFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
  audioFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  audioFile.Flush();
}
 }
 var file = new MediaPlayerAudioFile() { Title = "RESPONSE AUDIO" };
 file.Sources.Add(new MediaPlayerSource() 
 { Path = filePath, MimeType = "audio/mpeg" });
  player.Playlist.Add(file);
```

this code is not working. I have checked the path, it's working. I have tried the same path with html directly. Its working successfully. 
My html try is:

```
<telerik:RadMediaPlayer ID="player" runat="server" Width="320px" BackColor="Black" 
                            StartVolume="80" Height="200px">
                            <Sources>
                                <telerik:MediaPlayerSource Path="~/App_Temp/test.mp3" />
                            </Sources>

                        </telerik:RadMediaPlayer>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Path `string filePath =Server.MapPath("~/App_Temp/") + "test.mp3";` you specified here isn't exactly suitable for the RadMediaPlayer in the code behind.

Try changing to a relative path should make it work for you. Something like below

```
var filePath = Page.ResolveUrl("~/App_Temp/test.mp3");
var file = new MediaPlayerAudioFile() { Title = "RESPONSE AUDIO" };
file.Sources.Add(new MediaPlayerSource() { Path = filePath, MimeType = "audio/mpeg", });
player.Sources.Clear();
player.AutoPlay = false;
player.Playlist.Add(file);
```

Hope it helps